# Why is my Chrome extension popup not repainting?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a Google Chrome extension for internal users of our web-based product, where they can manage their feature flags. It's a simple UI that includes a notice that needs to be accepted, a textarea where people can enter new feature flags for themselves, and a list of those flags with a delete button and checkbox. The extension then adds the flags to the query parameters automatically whenever you visit the product, so they are enabled.

This works great! Most of the time at least.. I haven't been able to figure out why just yet, but there are cases where users click on the icon, the popup opens, and the html of the popup is not responding properly. Clicking on toggles doesn't uncheck the checkbox, clicking the delete button doesn't remove the feature flag, and focussing the textbox doesn't show a cursor or any text after you start typing. However, if you make changes and close and re-open the popup, the changes did get saved.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Below is the code. Irrelevant parts have been replaced with `SNIP`.

manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "SNIP",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "SNIP",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "SNIP",
        "default_icon": "SNIP.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": false
    },
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "permissions": [
        "storage",
        "webNavigation",
        "tabs"
    ]
}
```

popup.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            SNIP
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>Important notice:</h3>
        <ol>
            SNIP (just some li's with text in here)
        </ol>
        <button id="accept-notice">Accept</button>
        <div id="feature-flag-container" class="hidden">
            <h3>Feature flags:</h3>
            <div id="feature-flag-list"></div>
            <input id="new-feature-flag" type="text" />
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

popup.js

```
const acceptNoticeButton = document.getElementById("accept-notice");
const featureFlagContainer = document.getElementById("feature-flag-container");
const featureFlagList = document.getElementById("feature-flag-list");
const newFeatureFlagInput = document.getElementById("new-feature-flag");

let existingFlags = [];

chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ msg: "open_popup" });
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(request => {
    Object.keys(request.featureFlags).forEach(flag => {
        addFeatureFlagNode(flag, !!request.featureFlags[flag]);
    });
    if (request.acceptedNotice) {
        acceptNoticeButton.click();
    }
});

acceptNoticeButton.onclick = () => {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ msg: "accept_notice" });
    acceptNoticeButton.classList.add("hidden");
    featureFlagContainer.classList.remove("hidden");
}

function removeFeatureFlag(e) {
    const parent = e.target.parentNode;
    const flag = e.target.parentNode.children[1].innerText;

    existingFlags = existingFlags.filter(f => f !== flag);

    parent.remove();
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ msg: "remove_flag", flag });
}

function toggleFeatureFlag(e) {
    const flag = e.target.parentNode.children[1].innerText;
    const value = e.target.checked === true;
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ msg: "toggle_flag", flag, value });
}

function addFeatureFlagNode(flag, checked) {
    existingFlags.push(flag);

    const checkbox = document.createElement("input");
    checkbox.type = "checkbox";
    checkbox.checked = checked === false ? false : true;
    checkbox.onchange = toggleFeatureFlag;

    const text = document.createElement("p");
    text.innerText = flag;

    const del = document.createElement("button");
    del.innerText = "Delete";
    del.onclick = removeFeatureFlag;

    const container = document.createElement("div");
    container.appendChild(checkbox);
    container.appendChild(text);
    container.appendChild(del);

    featureFlagList.appendChild(container);
}

newFeatureFlagInput.onkeydown = e => {
    const flag = e.target.value;
    if (e.key === "Enter" && flag && !existingFlags.includes(flag)) {
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ msg: "add_flag", flag });
        addFeatureFlagNode(flag);
        e.target.value = "";
    }
}
```

background.js

```
const urls = [SNIP];
const environments = [SNIP];
const worksOn = [SNIP];
const options = [];
urls.forEach(url => {
    environments.forEach(environment => {
        worksOn.forEach(link => {
            options.push(`https://${url}${environment}.SNIP.com/${link}/`);
        });
    });
});

const state = { acceptedNotice: false, featureFlags: {} };
chrome.storage.sync.get(["acceptedNotice", "featureFlags"], result => {
    state.acceptedNotice = result.acceptedNotice;
    state.featureFlags = result.featureFlags || {};
});

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(({ msg, flag, value }) => {
    if (msg === "open_popup") {
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage(state);
        return
    }

    if (msg === "accept_notice") {
        state.acceptedNotice = true;
    } else if (msg === "add_flag") {
        state.featureFlags[flag] = true;
    } else if (msg === "remove_flag") {
        delete state.featureFlags[flag];
    } else if (msg === "toggle_flag") {
        state.featureFlags[flag] = value;
    }
    chrome.storage.sync.set(state);
});

chrome.webNavigation.onBeforeNavigate.addListener(event => {
    if (options.find(option => event.url.indexOf(option) === 0)) {
        const flags = Object.keys(state.featureFlags).filter(flag => state.featureFlags[flag] === true)
        const url = event.url.split("?");
        const queryParams = (url[1] || "").split("&").filter(param => !!param).map(param => {
            const split = param.split("=");
            return { key: split[0], value: split[1] };
        });
        const initialLength = queryParams.length;
        flags.forEach(flag => {
            if (!queryParams.find(param => param.key === flag)) {
                queryParams.push({ key: flag });
            }
        });
        if (queryParams.length !== initialLength) {
            chrome.tabs.update(event.tabId, {
                url: `${url[0]}?${queryParams.map(param =>
                    param.value ? `${param.key}=${param.value}` : param.key
                ).join("&")}`
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: You're using an event page which unloads after 5 seconds of **its own** inactivity so when it autoloads next time the state variables are all blank. 1) You don't need to maintain any global variables at all: just use chrome.storage in your popup.js. 2) You can unregister and then register again the webNavigation listener - it should be a named global function - with a URL filter parameter so Chrome triggers it only on a URL match. 3) Instead of sending a response message you should send a response via sendResponse as shown in [the examples](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging).

Comment: What do you mean with _an event page_? Either way I think it's fine that the state of the popup gets lost, because it will just re-instantiate itself next time it gets opened.

Comment: No, it's not fine and the state won't rebuild when onMessage is triggered. The event page is the background page declared with persistent:false.

Comment: I've been doing some more research today and realise now that I misunderstood. You were talking about the state of `background.js`, where I thought you were talking about `popup.js`.
I've noticed that, even with no code in `background.js` and `popup.js` not being loaded in the html, the popup is just not responding. The native text input isn't getting focus or showing any typed characters. When I remove the `background` section from `manifest.json` however, everything works as expected.

Comment: Without trying it locally myself there's nothing I can add because the synopsis just doesn't compute.

Comment: @J.Hellemans did you eventually figure this out?